# Magento 2 same product with multiple product costs prices

Tags: magento, magento2, sku

I have an issue right now and I believe many people might have this issue I am wondering if someone has found a work around so my issue is I have products that I buy stock for on a daily basis due to excahnge rate and other things the same product sometimes costs me different every time so my issue is,

If I have a Samsung watch I have 5 units in stock that cost me £35 Then I see a good deal on them and buy another 10 units these cost me £30 but I still have the 5 units in stock that cost me £35 so how can I upload/update the 10 units making 15 units in total but have a seperate cost price for the 10 units compared to the 5 units as I need this for reporting profit and loss reports.

So Ideally I want to be able to update my stock qty each time I do so I need to set a new cost price for that same product for selected amount of qtys,

Right now I am currently making the same product/SKU Multiple times because the product is the same but has cost me multiple by prices and I do not want to not have it listed for sale until the other stock sells and I do not want to keep making multiple products as customers think the products are different..

Any help will be strongly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you check Tire Price concept in magento ?

I think this will full fill your requirement.

Let me know if you have any query.